# how to clean Pi's resources from using Xming sessions?

Tags: raspbian, ssh, putty

How to clean the Pi's resources from the many previous sessions I started using PuTTy? as I found many posts saying it consumes part of the memory, and it can't overwrite it everytime I open a session.

Comment: could you please provide a link to "many posts saying it consumes part of the memory"? otherwise it's very unclear, what exactly is wrong and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to access my pi using Xming sessions and there is error PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted I found that it is due to low memory when xauth list I find 2 auth. not only one .